# macOS Sonoma widgets transparency issues

Tags: macos, desktop, sonoma, widgets

I'm having an issue where widgets don't preserve transparency when switching between virtual desktops.

Here's what it looks like after swapping virtual desktops:

[image: before]

Here it's displayed correctly after after performing the "show desktop" gesture:

[image: after]

I have already tried doing a settings soft-reset and replacing the widget but the issue/bug continues. Any solutions?